# How to use MERGE or Upsert Sql statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, sql-update, upsert

How can i use `MERGE` Sql Statement or `UPDATE` statement for my below code. I am having a columnName called `MachineName`, other column values change but MachineName doesnot change. If the Column `MachineName` changes i need to insert the new values in a secondrow. If not i need to Update the same row. How can i do this. Is it a right approach ?  Please help

```
MERGE INTO [devLaserViso].[dbo].[Machine] WITH (HOLDLOCK) 
USING [devLaserViso].[dbo].[Machine] 
ON (MachineName = MachineName)
  WHEN MATCHED 
       THEN UPDATE SET MachineName = L1,ProgramName= ancdh.pgm, TotalCount= 10, RightCount=4, 
                       LeftCount= 3,ErrorCode=0,FinishingTime=fsefsefef
  WHEN NOT MATCHED 
       THEN INSERT (MachineName, ProgramName, TotalCount, RightCount, LeftCount, ErrorCode, FinishingTime) 
            VALUES (L02, djiwdn.pgm, 11, 5, 4, 0, dnwdnwoin);
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be very enlightening.  You are doing a self join, and the logic doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load the new Machine data in a Temporary table and then can use the Merge statement as follows to update the records for which there is already a record in Machine table and will insert a new record if it does not exists in Machine table.

```
MERGE [devLaserViso].[dbo].[Machine] t WITH (HOLDLOCK) 
USING [devLaserViso].[dbo].[TempMachine] s
ON (s.MachineName = t.MachineName)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET t.MachineName = s.MachineName,t.ProgramName =s.ProgramName
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT (MachineName,ProgramName) VALUES (s.MachineName, s.ProgramName);
```

Comment: That means i have to create a Table called TempMachine. ?

Comment: Yes, create TempMachine and load new data in this table.

Answer (score 4):

I've had success in the past "Selecting" the values to upsert into the USING section of the MERGE command:

```
MERGE INTO [devLaserViso].[dbo].[Machine] WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS Target
USING (SELECT 'L1' AS MachineName, 'ancdh.pgm' AS ProgramName, 10 AS TotalCount, 
   4 AS RightCount, 3 AS LeftCount, 0 AS ErrorCode, 'fsefsefef' AS FinishingTime) AS Source
ON (Target.MachineName = Source.MachineName)
  WHEN MATCHED 
       THEN UPDATE SET ProgramName= Source.ProgramName, TotalCount= Source.TotalCount, 
          RightCount= Source.RightCount, LeftCount= Source.LeftCount, 
          ErrorCode= Source.ErrorCode, FinishingTime= Source.FinishingTime
  WHEN NOT MATCHED 
       THEN INSERT (MachineName, ProgramName, TotalCount, RightCount, LeftCount, ErrorCode, FinishingTime) 
            VALUES (Source.MachineName, Source.ProgramName, Source.TotalCount, Source.RightCount, 
                   Source.LeftCount, Source.ErrorCode, Source.FinishingTime);
```