# How to insert a new row to a table only if when same value does not exist, else update the related contents?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2010, insert-update, on-duplicate-key

**Table:**

> emergency_tab (`user_id`, `emergency_no`)

and

> Constraints (`user_id` [`primary key`])

When `id` and `no` are received, I'm required to `insert` those values to `user_id` and `emergency_no` columns in the `emergency_tab`. And if there exist a column with same `user_id`, I just wanted to update the `emergency_no` only, no need to `insert` new row.

I'm using `Visual Studio 2010` and `MS SQL Server 2008` inbuilt in `vs10`

Comment: Show the code you are working on so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working

```
 IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM emergency_tab WHERE user_id='?')<>0
    BEGIN
         --UPDATE
    END 

ELSE    
     BEGIN
       --INSERT
     END
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is called an "upsert", you can use the MERGE keyword, e.g.:

```
MERGE [devLaserViso].[dbo].[Machine] t WITH (HOLDLOCK) 
USING [devLaserViso].[dbo].[TempMachine] s
ON (s.MachineName = t.MachineName)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET t.MachineName = s.MachineName,
               t.ProgramName =s.ProgramName
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
    INSERT (MachineName,ProgramName) VALUES (s.MachineName, s.ProgramName);
```

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/50232866